# How to dynamicly get form field value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Form with id `id='address_information'` follow each id for the field

how can I get the value dynamicly from `id='address_information'` of form instead of just typing one by one like this

```
var data = {
    for: 'address_information',
    address: $('#address_information').find('#address').val(),
    duration: $('#address_information').find('#duration').val(),
    phone_number: $('#address_information').find('#phone_number').val(),
    province: $('#address_information').find('#province').val(),
    city: $('#address_information').find('#city').val(),
    district: $('#address_information').find('#district').val(),
    village: $('#address_information').find('#village').val(),
    address_type: $('#address_information').find('#address_type').val(),
    residency_status: $('#address_information').find('#residency_status').val()
};
```

I want something like foreach the form then get the value from each id of form

Comment: serialize the form `$("#address_information").serializeArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to get it as an array of values for further modifications you could use

```
$("#address_information").serializeArray()
```

if you want it to be sent along with some ajax request you could use it like

```
{data: $("#address_information").serialize()}
```